# Customize wpf calendar for specific region

Tags: c#, wpf, calendar

hi how can i change calendar months name? week names? also how can i remove days and add days based on specific region for example PersianCalendar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the `Language` property:

```
<Calendar Language="fa-IR" />
```

You may also want to read [this](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=persianculture).